# How can I get the length of a deferred Model in CanJS?

Tags: javascript, canjs, canjs-model

I am getting a model deferred object with a structure like this:

[image]

How can I find out how many objects are present inside this object (in this case, three). If I use `Object.keys(myObject).length`, it includes the object observer and other data also like _computeBindings,_bindings etc. I have even tried to use `hasOwnProperty` while calculating the length but its not giving me desired result.

One way I can figure out is to iterate over the index and get the last index value like this:

```
can.each(myObject,function(myObject,index){
// Get the last index value and put it into some variable
});
```

Is there an API for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can.Map has a [keys](http://canjs.com/docs/can.Map.keys.html) function that will give you an Array of the keys in your Map and from that you can get how many Objects by checking that Array's length.

Using a can.List as your data structure would also work. The keys in your data are numeric and you need to check the length, all things that can.List is built for.

Comment: can.Map.keys(myObject).length will solve the purpose :) Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `myObject.attr('length')`

Answer (score 0):

The model _data attribute contains a copy of just the model without the bindings. The easiest way to do this is to use:

```
Object._data.length
```